# «Не женские проблемы» — слитно или раздельно?

Tags: орфография, частица-не, прилагательные

В этом предложении какое написание выбрать?
**Женский подход к решению не женских** (неженских) **проблем.**
*Неженский* — не свойственный женщине. То есть писать слитно?

Answer (score 2):

Верно слитное написание.

> Слитно пишется не с именами прилагательными, которые не лишаются при
> этом утвердительного смысла, а лишь приобретают противоположное
> значение. Такие прилагательные имеют синонимы без не:
>
> ```
> невеселый (грустный), неглубокий (мелкий), недружелюбный (враждебный), неплохой (хороший); ср.: На берегу их провожали две фигуры небольших (маленьких) людей: Федератовна и Умрищев (Плат.); Матвей очень дивился тому, что у Димы оказался такой непостоянный (изменчивый) характер (Кор.); Утро оказалось неудачное (Наб.); Еще фараоны знали секрет повиновения: чтобы держать народ в страхе, карай не виновных, карай невинных (из газ.).
> ```
>
> [[gramma.ru](https://i.stack.imgur.com/boW6A.png)]

В данном случае смысл утвердительный:
*«Женский подход к решению неженских [мужских] проблем»*.

Однако если будет смысл отрицания «женскости», то будет писаться отдельно.

Например, название книги: «[У войны не женское лицо](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3_%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B_%D0%BD%D0%B5_%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%BE)».

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Источник изображения:
Автор: Издательство Мастацкая литература - http://zhabinkalib.by/images/rabochee/2015/raonaya_bibl/70_let/4.png, Добросовестное использование, https://ru.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?curid=6035608